# Using Gnome Terminal Command in Putty

Tags: putty, gnome-terminal

I am using Putty to SSH remote Linux virtual machine. All is well except that I can't get Gnome terminal command working in Putty. Some of these commands are:

```
Ctrl + A or Home

Moves the cursor to the start of a line.

Ctrl+ E or End

Moves the cursor to the end of a line.

Esc + B

Moves to the beginning of the previous or current word.

Ctrl + K

Deletes from the current cursor position to the end of the line.

Ctrl + U

Deletes from the start of the line to the current cursor position.

Ctrl + W

Deletes the word before the cursor.

Alt + B

Goes back one word at a time.

Alt + F

Moves forward one word at a time.

Alt + C

Capitalizes letter where cursor is and moves to end of word.
```

These shortcuts are in fact quite common among Linux users. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to get them working in Putty. For instance, whenever I press CTRL+A in putty, it prints out ^A instead of jumping to start of line.

Have you encountered the same situation or is it that this issue is never addressed? Yet I hope someone could share that basically it'd be a few steps to get it working.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: moved to Super User http://superuser.com/questions/867588/using-gnome-terminal-command-in-putty